# Quaternion.Euler and transform.Translate

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a simple gameobject that you can move and rotate using the keyboard. It works well right now, but my only problem is that it keeps rotating the object's X. I want to lock it at certain position, but still be able to rotate the gameobject. I tried locking through RigidBody but it didn't work.

I also tried Quanternion.Euler, but then a weird bug happened. When I try to move up the rotation locks on Z=90 and Y=-90 and when I try to move down the rotation locks to Z=-90 and Y=90. This happens only when I try to change the X to -90 through Quanternion.Euler. My guess is that the bug has to do with Transform.Translate, the function I use to move my gameobject around with it rotation.

here is my code:

```
   transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, angularSpeed*Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.Self);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90f, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0,-1, 0);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0,0, 0.2f);
        angularSpeed =-20;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -0.2f);
        angularSpeed =20;
    }
```

Comment: I guess what happens there is a so called [Gimbal-Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

Comment: Yes, i think @derHugo is right, you should check the 3d model for whether their pivot is at (0,0,0). Or you can create a empty gameObject, make the 3d model as a child gameObject and rotate the parent gameObject instead.